# Android user interface issues

Tags: android, user-interface

I'm trying to build an Android application and I'm struggling to finish Quiz module. So in this module, I need to insert difficulty settings for the questions (Easy, Medium and Hard).
For my first XML layout, I set method to return difficulty settings.

```
/**
 * Method to return the difficulty settings
 * @return
 */
private int getDifficultySettings() {
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(Constants.SETTINGS, 0);
    int diff = settings.getInt(Constants.DIFFICULTY, Constants.MEDIUM);
    return diff;
```

For another layout which display the difficulty settings.

```
/**
 * Method to update default check box
 */
private void updateButtonWithPreferences() {
    RadioButton c1 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.easySetting);
    RadioButton c2 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.mediumSetting);
    RadioButton c3 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.hardSetting);

    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(Constants.SETTINGS, 0);
    int diff = settings.getInt(Constants.DIFFICULTY, Constants.MEDIUM);

    switch (diff)
    {
    case Constants.EASY : 
        c1.toggle();
        break;

    case Constants.MEDIUM : 
        c2.toggle();
        break;

    case Constants.HARD :
        c3.toggle();
        break;  
    }
}
```

The problem is I can only retrieve the question from database when I choose Medium setting. Can you, Android experts give some ideas for me? Thank you. :)

For diffifulty java code:-

```
public class SettingsActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.settings);

    Button updateBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nextBtn);
    updateBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

    updateButtonWithPreferences();

}

private void updateButtonWithPreferences() {
    RadioButton c1 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.easySetting);
    RadioButton c2 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.mediumSetting);
    RadioButton c3 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.hardSetting);

    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(Constants.SETTINGS, 0);
    int diff = settings.getInt(Constants.DIFFICULTY, Constants.MEDIUM);

    switch (diff)
    {
    case Constants.EASY : 
        c1.toggle();
        break;

    case Constants.MEDIUM : 
        c2.toggle();
        break;

    case Constants.EXTREME :
        c3.toggle();
        break;  
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {

    if (!checkSelected())
    {
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(Constants.SETTINGS, 0);
        Editor e = settings.edit();
        e.putInt(Constants.DIFFICULTY, getSelectedSetting());
        e.commit();
        finish();
    }

}

private boolean checkSelected() {
    RadioButton c1 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.easySetting);
    RadioButton c2 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.mediumSetting);
    RadioButton c3 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.hardSetting);
    return (c1.isChecked() || c2.isChecked() || c3.isChecked());
}

private int getSelectedSetting() {
    RadioButton c1 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.easySetting);
    RadioButton c2 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.mediumSetting);
    if (c1.isChecked())
    {
        return Constants.EASY;
    }
    if (c2.isChecked())
    {
        return Constants.MEDIUM;
    }

    return Constants.EXTREME;
}
```

}

For database java code:-

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.tmm.android.chuck/databases/";
private static String DB_NAME = "questionsDb";
private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase; 
private final Context myContext;

public DBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
    this.myContext = context;
}   

public void createDataBase() throws IOException{
    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
    if(!dbExist)
    {
        this.getReadableDatabase();

        try {
            copyDataBase(); 
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new Error("Error copying database");
        }
    }
}

private boolean checkDataBase(){
    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
    try{
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    }catch(SQLiteException e){

    }
    if(checkDB != null){
        checkDB.close();
    }

    return checkDB != null ? true : false;
}

private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{

    InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();

}

public void openDataBase() throws SQLException{
    String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
}

@Override
public synchronized void close() {
    if(myDataBase != null)
        myDataBase.close();
    super.close();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
}

public List<Question> getQuestionSet(int difficulty, int numQ){
    List<Question> questionSet = new ArrayList<Question>();
    Cursor c = myDataBase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM QUESTIONS WHERE DIFFICULTY=" + difficulty +
            " ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT " + numQ, null);
    while (c.moveToNext()){
        Question q = new Question();
        q.setQuestion(c.getString(1));
        q.setAnswer(c.getString(2));
        q.setOption1(c.getString(3));
        q.setOption2(c.getString(4));
        q.setOption3(c.getString(5));
        q.setRating(difficulty);
        questionSet.add(q);
    }
    return questionSet;
}
```

}

This code for my first XML layout. so method getQuestionSet() was from here.

```
public class SplashActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.welcome);

    Button playBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.playBtn);
    playBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    Button settingsBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.settingsBtn);
    settingsBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    Button rulesBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.rulesBtn);
    rulesBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    Button exitBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.exitBtn);
    exitBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent i;

    switch (v.getId()){
    case R.id.playBtn :

        List<Question> questions = getQuestionSetFromDb();

        GamePlay c = new GamePlay();
        c.setQuestions(questions);
        c.setNumRounds(getNumQuestions());
        ((ChuckApplication)getApplication()).setCurrentGame(c);  

        i = new Intent(this, QuestionActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(i, Constants.PLAYBUTTON);
        break;

    case R.id.rulesBtn :
        i = new Intent(this, RulesActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(i, Constants.RULESBUTTON);
        break;

    case R.id.settingsBtn :
        i = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(i, Constants.SETTINGSBUTTON);
        break;

    case R.id.exitBtn :
        finish();
        break;
    }
}

private List<Question> getQuestionSetFromDb() throws Error {
    int diff = getDifficultySettings();
    int numQuestions = getNumQuestions();
    DBHelper myDbHelper = new DBHelper(this);
    try {
        myDbHelper.createDataBase();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        throw new Error("Unable to create database");
    }
    try {
        myDbHelper.openDataBase();
    }catch(SQLException sqle){
        throw sqle;
    }
    List<Question> questions = myDbHelper.getQuestionSet(diff, numQuestions);
    myDbHelper.close();
    return questions;
}

private int getDifficultySettings() {
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(Constants.SETTINGS, 0);
    int diff = settings.getInt(Constants.DIFFICULTY, Constants.MEDIUM);
    return diff;
}

private int getNumQuestions() {
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(Constants.SETTINGS, 0);
    int numRounds = settings.getInt(Constants.NUM_ROUNDS, 20);
    return numRounds;
}
```

}

Comment: It looks like you're only pulling the difficulty setting from the preferences (which I'm guessing you don't ever populate - you set the default to medium).  I don't see anything about pulling a question from the database.  Could you post more code?  We'll need to see where you get the question.  Also, when do you set the difficulty?  You might have a problem there, too.

Comment: Hi Todd.
I create the database using sqlite database browser. The file is inserted in assets folder. In Question table, I put 7 objects:- ID, question, answer, incorrect1, incorrect2, incorrect3, and difficulty. I try to use switch but it doesn't work.

Comment: I already put some code in the question. :)

Comment: Where do you call `getQuestionSet()`?

Comment: Hi Geobits. I put another code for getQuestionSet() :)

Comment: Nothing jumps out at me here right away, but I find it very suspicious that your default setting is medium, and that happens to be the only one that works.  You should split the problem in half: manually look in the database and see that you have questions with difficulties besides medium.  If you don't, that's an easy fix.  If you do, then determine if your query is incorrect.  Step into `getQuestionSetFromDb()` and see if the values are what you expect them to be.

Comment: Regarding your thought on default setting, I have try to use the switch in order to control the setting. However, it doesn't work. So, I try to setting the difficulty control as default and it works only on one value. In my database I already set up the difficulty values into 3: 1-> Easy, 2-> Medium and 3-> Hard. Anyway, thank you on your opinion. I think I need to explore more on my code. :)

Comment: Dear Todd and Geobits, I just want to ask. It is possible to declare static for variable while use   findViewById?